# Custom post types not using archive structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, archives

I've been banging my head against my iMac trying to figure out what's wrong. I've also trolled these archives and have tried the following things to fix:

- flush permalinks
- remove possibly conflicting categories/slugs
- `flush_rewrite_rules( false );`
- `'has_archive' => true`, `'has_archive' => false` (as well as many similar `$args` variations
- `archive-{CPT}.php`, `archive-{CPTSlug}.php`
- `category-{CPT}.php`, `category-{CPTSlug}.php`
- `content-{CPT}.php`, `content-{CPTSlug}.php`
- `{CPT}-archive.php`, `{CPTSlug}-archive.php`
- change the slugs of the CPT and taxonomies and flushed permalinks

ALL attempts return a 404 page when visiting `www.site.com/CPTSlug` or `www.site.com/CPT`. The individual posts of the CPT however, display correctly at the URL `www.site.com/CPTSlug/post_title`.

When I had these set as categories instead of custom post types it worked perfectly. If anyone out there can spot the problem I would be most grateful.

```
function register_artists_post_type() {
    register_post_type('artists',array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Artists' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Artist' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add Artist','Artist' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Artist' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Artist' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Artist' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Artist' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Artists' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Artists Found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Artists In Trash' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => ''
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title','editor','excerpt','custom-fields','thumbnail' ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'artists'),
        'taxonomies' => array('large_feature','small_feature'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
    ));
}
add_action('init','register_artists_post_type');
```

There were previously categories called "Artists" (slug = `artists`) as well as child categories with slugs of `large_feature` and `small_feature`. Those have all been deleted from the database and have been replaced with the custom post type below and the slugs you see in the registration.

The theme files are as follows (though I don't think this is the problem since it's a 404 page displayed, but in the interest of giving as much relevant information as possible...)

`archive.php`
`archive_{cpt}.php`
`category.php`
`single.php`
`single_{cpt}.php`

The single posts are correctly posting using `single_{cpt}.php`. Archives however, are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any golden answers to this problem, but for the sake of closing this thing out, I *did* get it fixed.

For anyone else having this problem. I would highly suggest making a wordpress sandbox and building it out in a fresh install. I did that and it worked perfectly. The frustrating thing is, after adding back all the functions and plugins one by one, I never ran into the same problem, even though I was working with the *exact* same database, the *exact* same plugins, the *exact* same template files and the *exact* same functions within `functions.php`.

The only difference is that I had been basing my theme off Twenty Eleven and this time I went with Starkers, a bare-bones theme intended for theme developers. So it had to have been something native to Twenty Eleven that was conflicting. What conflicted will sadly remain a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to filter rewrite_urls array and create rules for you custom post type.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do that?

Comment: On that line of thought, I changed `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'artists')` to `'rewrite' => true` and flushed the permalinks. That at least got it to come up as `site.com/cpt/` which is a start. So I changed it back to `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'artists')` and now it's coming up as `site.com/artists/` but it's not using the archive template or archive.php. I'm in the process now of trying to figure out what file it's using, but I have body text in all the docs saying what the filename is and I don't see that anywhere on the page. Strange.

Comment: add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules_array_custom');
 function rewrite_rules_array_custom($_rules){
  $rules = array();
  foreach($_rules as $key=>$rule){
   if (strpos($key, 'artists') !== false){
    if (!isset($rulesSetted)){
     $rulesSetted = true;
     $rules['artists/([^/]+).html?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=artists&artists=$matches[2]&paged=1';
    }
   } else {
    $rules[$key] = $rule;
   }
  
  }
  return $rules;
 }

Comment: Please add code to the answer, comments are unsuitable for it.

Comment: i am sorry for that. tried to edit but can't do that more in 5 minutes..

http://pastebin.com/Tme0W7DJ
this is  a sample of rewrites_rules_array filter. jsut a sample. you need to palce correct hook inside and palce your own rules. it helps to create miracles but require a lot of testing. i am actualy writing test case each time while do such things. 

you also can use var_dump function to see whats inside of the array that you get... and change it as you wish =)

Comment: Found it. For some odd reason it's using `page.php`. I can force it to use a certain template, but would like to know what is going wrong to cause it to use this instead of the archive page.

Comment: Bah. I had a page set up from forever ago called "artists" and now that I deleted that from the pages area it's not working again. How is it that wordpress doesn't see this post type has an archive?

Comment: I decided to take someone else's advice and start a fresh install to make a test area for this. All this code works like a charm in the other install, even using the same database, so something else in my theme is conflicting with it. _sigh_

It'll be an arduous process, but I'll start fresh in the morning and post whatever I find here so maybe someone else will be spared the headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
'hierarchical' => false,
));
```

Try removing the comma after this. It has to be throwing an error on that.

Comment: that didn't work :(